# HTML img doesnt show bug

Tags: html, adobe

Before you read the title "This topic does not exist".

I have a problem with an image I made on Adobe Illustrator.
When I try to use it in my html it shows in my Neon Eclipse PHP environment but if I want to use it in the explorer browser it only shows the alt="Background". Further I use XAMPP to host my local server and I use Windows 10.

Script :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HomePage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Background">
        <img alt="BackgroundIMG" src="C:\Users\Rik van haaren\Desktop\Website\afbeeldingen\Achtergrond.png">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Neon Eclipse environment.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6yNX.png)

[Web browser img.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6KMh.png)

Comment: btw i test other img and they work just fine.

Comment: Oh my.. Do you use an webserver like xampp or wampp ? You shouldnt write the full path as src. You should be able to short it to /afbeeldingen/Achtergrond.png or /Achtergrond.png based on your index.html. The folder with your html is your starting position, urls should be relative to that. Oh and it has nothing to do with the image or adobe

Comment: @Doomenik I use XAMPP my apologies that I forgot to write that. and on your solution I need to add include right?

Comment: @Doomenik I placed the img in my project and change the line to this ..\afbeeldingen\Achtergrond.png and it worked how can it be that its works fine now?

Comment: Simple thing, you work with an webserver. This little guy defines your root directory in your case the folder Website. So your Webserver already points to C:\Users\Rik van haaren\Desktop\Website\ so you just have to go further. But remember on the other hand you cant acess things in front of the folder "Website". You cant acess things like C:\Users\Rik van haaren\Desktop\New Folder...This is an restriction by your webserver, just think your project root is like an virtual machine which doens´t know your pc :)